# What's the difference between "in the same year" and "the same year"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbials

> It remained constant at this level till May the same year.

In this sentence, can we use 'in' before the noun phrase 'the same year'?

What is the difference between 'in the same year' and 'the same year'?

Answer (score 3):

As a native British English speaker, the sentence as written: "It remained constant at this level till May the same year" sounds fine, and I wouldn't say "in the same year" in that context.

I might say:
"It remained constant at this level till May **of** the same year", or
"It remained constant at this level till May **that** same year".

On the other hand, I might say:
"I went on holiday twice **in the same year**"

Answer (score 0):

Both 'the same year' and 'in the same year' are fine.

It remained constant at this level till May **the same year**. or

It remained constant at this level till May **in the same year**. or

It remained constant at this level till May **of the same year**.

It remained constant at this level till May (in/of) **this same year**. or

It remained constant at this level till May (in/of) **that same year**.

(We can use 'in' or 'of' before the same year.)

[We can use 'this same year' or 'that same year' instead of 'the same year'.]